# Does the compiler optimise condition checking for `while(true)` loops? (C++)

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I am curious as to weather or not the compiler would optimize out condition checks for a `while` loop if the condition is the constant term `true`.
What about `for(;;)`, are any cpu instructions executed after running the last line and before running the top line again?

Comment: Use godbolt or compile to assembly on your own and check. A compiler will likely just insert a `goto` and a label. Try with different optimization levels and see how it changes.

Comment: You can check this and much more here : https://godbolt.org/z/Kzn985Wv4 This site will compile your code using different compilers for different platforms and will show you the generated assembly code. And you can play around with optimization flags too. Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

It is very unlikely that compliers in optimized mode would produce different machine code for `while(true)` and `for(;;)` loops.

`for(;;)` might be preferred as it is less likely to produce warnings about loop expressions always evaluated to true, and being more idiomatic form of a loop without condition, but these reasons aren't strong enough to consider `while(true)` significantly worse.

These loops may be transformed by compiler to unconditional jumps backwards. But if there's exit condition in the middle, they may be transformed to do-while loops (conditional jumps backwards), or, if actual number of repetitions can be proved to be finite, even unrolled. Sure compiler will not check always true or non-existing condition, except possibly in unoptimized (debug) mode.

Comment: I like `while (7)`, because `7` is lucky (in my culture). Avoid `while (13)`.